# Unknown opcode 'CBZ' using the uVision ARM compiler

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, arm, thumb

Recently in my computer class we have stated working with the uVision ARM compiler. Now, I have done java for many years and understand how to program but ARM is giving me trouble.

The program I am aiming to create is one where we convert uppercase letters to lowercase letters and vice versa.

My code is as follows. Everything but the two if statements were provided by the teacher.

```
            AREA mydata,DATA
output  SPACE 50
          AREA mycode,CODE,ALIGN=2
          THUMB
          EXPORT __main
input     DCB   "The QUICK brown fOx",0
          DCD   0

__main   PROC
         LDR R0,=input  ;R0 has input ptr
         LDR R1,=output ;R1 has output ptr

loop     LDRB R2,[R0]   ;R2 has the next character
         CBZ R2,exit        ;if r2 == 0 go to exit
         STRB R2,[R1]   ;store R2 @ R1 (output ptr)
         if(R1>91 )
            SUB R1, #32
        else if(R1<91)
            ADD R1, #32

        B loop          ;do the next character
exit    MOV R2,#0       ;put in my byte of zero
        STRB R2,[R1]
done    B done          ;end
    ENDP
    END
```

Running this gives me the following errors (minus the name of the file because it's my full name):

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 5 (build 528)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'Target 1'
assembling (fileName).s...
(fileName).s(12): error: A1854E: Unknown opcode 'CBZ', maybe wrong target CPU?
(fileName).s(14): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode if(R1>91 , expecting opcode or Macro
(fileName).s(15): error: A1859E: Flag preserving form of this instruction not available
(fileName).s(16): error: A1157E: Syntax error following directive
(fileName).s(17): error: A1859E: Flag preserving form of this instruction not available
(fileName).s(20): error: A1859E: Flag preserving form of this instruction not available
".\Objects\new.axf" - 6 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:00
```

I've searched uVision's website for solutions and I can't seem to find any direction. Please help!
First post on Stack Overflow! Hope I did well!

Comment: you wrote this or you were give this and trying to understand it?   You have some arm documentation with the instruction set in it yes?  Is there a CBZ instruction?  You have the documentation for the assembler yes?  Is there if() then  else syntax for that assembler?

Comment: Assembly language doesn't use `if()` syntax, you have to "compile" that yourself into `cmp` / `bgt` (compare and branch instructions), or use ARM predicated execution to do it branchlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the target CPU you are compiling for. CBZ is only available in ARMv6T2 and above as can be seen in its [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaghefc.html).